# Ignoring errors in concurrent insertions

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, duplicates, sql-insert

I have a string vector `data` containing items that I want to insert into a table named `foos`. It's possible that some of the elements in `data` already exist in the table, so I must watch out for those.

The solution I'm using starts by transforming the `data` vector into virtual table `old_and_new`; it then builds virtual table `old` which contains the elements which are already present in `foos`; then, it constructs virtual table `new` with the elements
which are really new. Finally, it inserts the new elements in table `foos`.

```
WITH   old_and_new AS (SELECT unnest ($data :: text[]) AS foo),
       old AS (SELECT foo FROM foos INNER JOIN old_and_new USING (foo)),
       new AS (SELECT * FROM old_and_new EXCEPT SELECT * FROM old)
INSERT INTO foos (foo) SELECT foo FROM new
```

This works fine in a non-concurrent setting, but fails if concurrent threads
try to insert the same new element at the same time. I know I can solve this
by setting the isolation level to `serializable`, but that's very heavy-handed.

Is there some other way I can solve this problem? If only there was a way to
tell PostgreSQL that it was safe to ignore `INSERT` errors...

Comment: `serializable` isn't actually that "heavy".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, are there any benchmarks comparing performance of the different transaction isolation levels? It would be good to have a reference point when making such decisions.

Comment: See this: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Serializable and this: http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4179

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever your course of action is ([@Denis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16360750/939860) gave you quite a few options), this rewritten `INSERT` command will be *much* faster:

```
INSERT INTO foos (foo)
SELECT n.foo
FROM   unnest ($data::text[]) AS n(foo)
LEFT   JOIN foos o USING (foo)
WHERE  o.foo IS NULL
```

It also leaves a *much* smaller time frame for a possible race condition.
In fact, the time frame should be so small, that unique violations should only be popping up under heavy concurrent load or with huge arrays.

#### Dupes in the array?

Except, if you your problem is *built-in*. Do you have duplicates in the input array itself? In this case, transaction isolation is not going to help you. The enemy is within!

Consider this example / solution:

```
INSERT INTO foos (foo)
SELECT n.foo
FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT foo FROM unnest('{foo,bar,foo,baz}'::text[]) AS foo) n
LEFT   JOIN foos o USING (foo)
WHERE  o.foo IS NULL
```

I use `DISTINCT` in the subquery to eliminate the "sleeper agents", a.k.a. duplicates.

People tend to forget that the dupes may come *within* the import data.

#### Full automation

This function is one way to deal with concurrency for good. If a `UNIQUE_VIOLATION` occurs, the `INSERT` is just retried. The newly present rows are excluded from the new attempt automatically.

It does **not** take care of the opposite problem, that a row might have been deleted concurrently - this would not get re-inserted. One might argue, that this outcome is ok, since such a `DELETE` happened concurrently. If you want to prevent this, make use of `SELECT ... FOR SHARE` to protect rows from concurrent `DELETE`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_insert_array(_data text[], OUT ins_ct int) AS
$func$
BEGIN

LOOP
   BEGIN

   INSERT INTO foos (foo)
   SELECT n.foo
   FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT foo FROM unnest(_data) AS foo) n
   LEFT   JOIN foos o USING (foo)
   WHERE  o.foo IS NULL;

   GET DIAGNOSTICS ins_ct = ROW_COUNT;
   RETURN;

   EXCEPTION WHEN UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN     -- tag.tag has UNIQUE constraint.
      RAISE NOTICE 'It actually happened!'; -- hardly ever happens
   END;
END LOOP;

END
$func$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I made the function return the count of inserted rows, which is completely optional.

[**-> SQLfiddle demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0abc8/2)

Comment: +1: Not sure about Postgres, but if I was bulk inserting into Oracle I'd also be tempted to investigate ordering of the result set prior to insert in order to optimise index maintenance on the target table and/or improve the clustering factor for common queries. I'm not sure whether clustering factor is a statistic available to Postgres during query optimisation (I note the CLUSTER command however), but it ought to be a real benefit in theory. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the very comprehensive answer.  This really helps!

Comment: @DavidAldridge: Pre-sorting data / clustering has an impact, of course. If a query can pull a few data block with all needed data, that's faster than if it has to read blocks all over the place. My query uses `DISTINCT` to eliminate dupes, which normally orders the data in this step automatically. One might add `ORDER BY` (that has to agree with `DISTINCT`) explicitly. Usefulness depends. How many rows inserted at a time? Many random updates? What kind of queries are actually run? More about `CLUSTER` / `pg_repack` in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16390308/939860

Answer (score 3):

> Is there some other way I can solve this problem?

There are plenty, but none are a panacea...

You can't lock for inserts like you can do a `select for update`, since the rows don't exist yet.

You *can* lock the entire table, but that's even heavier handed that serializing your transactions.

You can use advisory locks, but be super wary about deadlocks. Sort new keys so as to obtain the locks in a consistent, predictable order. (Someone more knowledgeable with PG's source code will hopefully chime in, but I'm guessing that the predicate locks used in the serializable isolation level amount to doing precisely that.)

In pure sql you could also use a do statement to loop through the rows one by one, and trap the errors as they occur:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-do.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING

Similarly, you could create a convoluted upsert function and call it once per piece of data...

If you're building $data at the app level, you could run the inserts one by one and ignore errors.

And I'm sure I forgot some additional options...

Comment: With a fast enough insert and not too many sessions attempting to insert concurrently, it seems like might be worth considering a single advisory lock for the entire transaction rather than the "one per row" used in the documented examples: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html

Answer (score 0):

I like both Erwin and Denis' answers, but another approach might be to have concurrent sessions performing the unnesting and loading into a separate temporary table, and optionally eliminating what duplicates they can against the target table, and having a single session selecting from this temporary table, resolving temp table internal duplicates in an appropriate manner, inserting to the target table checking again for existing values, and deleting the selected temporary table records (in the same query using a common table expression).

This would be more batch oriented, in the style of a data warehouse extraction-load-transform paradigm, but would guarantee that no unique constraint issues would need to be dealt with.

Other advantages/disadvantages apply, such as decoupling the final insert from the data gathering (possible advantage), and needing to vacuum the temp table frequently (possible disadvantage), which may not be relevant to Jon's case, but might be useful info to others in the same situation.