# How to reduce index scan time for a postgresql IN query with ordered results?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I built a simple app for reading RSS feeds using rails and postgresql, but am running into performance issues when I try to query my `feed_entries` table for posts from more than one feed. An example query looks like this, to retrieve the 20 most recent entries for a given collection of feed ids:

`SELECT * FROM feed_entries WHERE feed_id IN (19, 21, 383, 1867, 3103) ORDER BY published_at DESC LIMIT 20;`

The `feed_entries` table has about 4 million rows in it, is hosted on Heroku Postgres with the Fugu plan, and it has a few indexes, including:

```
"index_feed_entries_on_feed_id_and_published_at" btree (feed_id, published_at)
"index_feed_entries_on_published_at" btree (published_at)
```

Here are the results of the query planner:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM feed_entries WHERE feed_id IN (19, 21, 383, 1867, 3103) ORDER BY published_at DESC LIMIT 20;

 Limit  (cost=4353.93..4353.94 rows=20 width=1016) (actual time=12172.275..12172.325 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=4353.93..4355.07 rows=2286 width=1016) (actual time=12172.268..12172.284 rows=20 loops=1)
     Sort Key: published_at
     Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 52kB
     ->  Index Scan using index_feed_entries_on_feed_id_and_published_at on feed_entries  (cost=0.00..4341.76 rows=2286 width=1016) (actual time=8.612..12169.504 rows=630 loops=1)
           Index Cond: (feed_id = ANY ('{19,21,383,1867,3103}'::integer[]))
Total runtime: 12172.520 ms
```

The planner looks like it's using the appropriate index, yet scanning the index still takes ~12 seconds, which strikes me as too long for a table that has 4 million rows. If I repeat the query planner exactly as above, then the second time it tells me that the whole thing takes only 2 ms, maybe that's simply because the results of the first query are cached, but it's still confusing to me. I also tried running `VACUUM ANALYZE` before running the query, but it made little difference. Additionally, if I query the table for a single feed_id, then the query planner uses an `Index Scan Backward using index_feed_entries_on_feed_id_and_published_at on feed_entries`, and total execution time is much faster, on the order of 20ms.

Are there other strategies I could adopt to optimize the performance of this relatively simple IN query?

Comment: What is the beahviour with a OR instead of IN in your request ?

Comment: the query plan looks different, it does a `Bitmap Index Scan on index_feed_entries_on_feed_id_and_published_at` for each of the feed_ids in the OR conditions. The total runtime decreased to ~3000 ms, though it's hard to know if that is somewhat related to cached results (I was experimenting with the old query not too long before trying this new one)

Comment: Just run each query several times to exclude caching effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another thing to try would be this alternative query form:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   feed_entries
JOIN  (unnest('{19,21,383,1867,3103}'::int[]) AS feed_id) sub USING (feed_id)
ORDER  BY published_at DESC
LIMIT  20;
```

Sort order of columns *does* matter in [multi-column indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html), though. Use:

```
CREATE index_feed_entries_2 ON feed_entries (feed_id, published_at DESC)
```

If you [`CLUSTER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-cluster.html) your table according to this index, this might give you another little boost, but effectiveness deteriorates with a lot of updates. Read the last chapter of this related answer for more info:
[Bitmap Heap Scan performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387090/bitmap-heap-scan-performance/16390308#16390308)

Of course, all [the usual advice on performance optimization](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization) applies, too.

Comment: Thanks! The CLUSTER seems to have made a meaningful improvement, though I'm a bit worried that will degrade over time as I add/remove rows from the table. Currently I've scheduled a weekly CLUSTER and VACUUM ANALYZE on the table. The DESC index though doesn't seem to make a difference: the query planner still uses the ASC index, even though the query is clearly sorting by descending

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an index with a DESC order.
Eg.

```
create index feed_entries_published_at_desc_idx on feed_entries ( published_at desc ) with (fillfactor=100);
```

You could try a similar (compound) index as above on (feed_id, published_at desc) to see how that works too.

Comment: The query planner *does* use that index now, but the results are still slow. also, why `fillfactor=100`? My understanding was that if you have a table that will be updated frequently, you should use a lower value for `fillfactor`?

Comment: Oh, the data is UPDATEd a lot? Sorry, I didn't get that from the question. If that's the case, then yeah, drop the fillfactor.
You say the index is already being used -- which one? Your original, or the one I suggested with a sort order of DESC?

Comment: @tws: Sort order on a single-column B-tree index has hardly any effect. Postgres can scan backwards at (almost) the same speed.